# Hammer projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I would like to use Hammer's projection in QGIS. I am providing the follow `proj` string:

```
+proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

But QGIS complains that it is invalid:

[image]

According to the [`proj` documentation](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/hammer.html) all parameters are optional, I would expected it to function like this.

I have QGIS 2.18.20 and `proj` 4.9.3.

Comment: Perhaps it means all of the supported parameters? Lat does not seem to belong to those. Have you tried with plain"+proj=hammer"?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove those and the other parameters, but I always get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `+hammer` is implemented in PROJ.4, it is not in GDAL.

In a OSGEO4W shell or Linux terminal, you can put some lon lat coordinates in a textfile `wgs.txt` and run

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs wgs.txt >hammer.txt
gdaltransform -s_srs "+init=epsg:4326" -t_srs "+proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" <wgs.txt >hammer.txt
```

The first one runs fine (using pure PROJ), while the second fails.

QGIS depends on GDAL, hence it can not use your projection string.

In most cases it is a matter of a missing inverse projection. Running

```
 proj -I +proj=hammer
 cs2cs +proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 hammer.txt >wgs84a.txt
```

with proj 4.8.0 returns an error in both lines:

```
 <proj>:
 inverse projection not available
 program abnormally terminated
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that the inverse projection has been implemented in Proj4 v4.9.3, so following an advice from http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-EqualEarth-projection-support-in-QGIS-td5375972.html a projection not known to GDAL can be added to QGIS with

```
 +proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +wktext +no_defs
```

which gives the expected image of the Earth:

[image]

and the command line tests work too:

```
 proj -I +proj=hammer +wktext <hammer.txt
 cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +wktext +no_defs wgs.txt >hammer.txt
 cs2cs +proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +wktext +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 hammer.txt >wgs84a.txt
 gdaltransform -s_srs "+init=epsg:4326" -t_srs "+proj=hammer +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +wktext +no_defs" <wgs.txt >hammer.txt
```

Comment: QGis issues the same error as in the question with the proj string in the update.

Comment: Strange. I just tested with QGIS 2.14, 2.18 and 3.2 on Linux Mint 17.3, 18, 19 and Ubuntu 16.04. Does proj -I work for you?

Comment: This is my environment: 
- Ubuntu 18.04
- proj 4.9.3
- QGis 2.18.20

Comment: Do the command line tests work for you?

Comment: This is all functioning now for me too. There are no updates logged to these packages since, but something got fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Out of the blue, GDAL stopped support this projection again. I opened [a new question on the matter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304770/21532).